# Bypassing grails view resolvers?

Tags: java, grails, spring-mvc, portlet, liferay

I'm trying to build a portlet within a grails application, and I've created a simple controller extending `AbstractController` which returns

`new ModelAndView('myportlet')` from `handleRequestInternal`. I also have a standard `Jstl view resolver` setup for `/WEB-INF/jsp` but no matter what I try, when I try to view the portlet within liferay I get the following stacktrace:

```
13:19:39,723 ERROR [DispatcherPortlet:559] Could not complete request
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.portlet.context.PortletRequestAttributes cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest(WebUtils.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.view.GrailsViewResolver.loadView(GrailsViewResolver.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.view.ScaffoldingViewResolver.loadView(ScaffoldingViewResolver.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherPortlet.java:1110)
```

It seems that if I could get around the `GrailsViewResolver`, I should be able to get my portlet up and running as I would in a normal spring application.

I'm using liferay 6, so the grails liferay plugin isn't an option. Is there anything I can do to make sure GrailsViewResolver doesn't try to resolve my view in `/WEB-INF/jsp`?

Comment: Can you please share your web.xml, portlet.xml and any other configuration xml you are using for your portlet? seems to be some configuration issue. without seeing them cant say much. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Grails, use it 100% and don't try to mix wildly different technologies. It'll save you pain in the long run.